# How to calculate the rate of reaction of Sodium and Chlorine

Tags: kinetics

$$\ce{2Na(s) + Cl2(g)   ->    2NaCl(s)}$$
How exactly do you calculate the reaction rate of the following equation?

Since reaction rate is usually calculated in moles per $\rm dm^3$ per second (M/s) and the reactants here are solid. I want to have a equation of $$R = K \times\ce{[Na]}^x\ce{[Cl]}^y$$

Comment: Reaction rate constant completely depends upon the reaction order (i.e. the stoichiometry of the slow step). What do you think the slow step is in this case? Also, there are plenty of first-order reactions that require one species to be excited or activated first (as well as other common reaction orders), so saying they're usually in units of $\frac{mol}{L\cdot s}$ is... I don't know. Well, a mistake, as I'm pretty sure you will find out on this question.

Comment: Nah, nevermind. This one comes out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rate laws are determined via experimental data. Reactant concentrations are held constant while others are modified in order to determine the effect of each reactant's concentration on a reaction. For this reason, one cannot determine the rate law from just a stoichiometric equation.
$$\ce{2Na + Cl2 -> 2NaCl}$$

We can propose reaction mechanisms to make an educated guess of the rate law:
\begin{align}
\ce{Na + Cl2 &-> NaCl + Cl}&&\text{(slow step)}\\
\ce{Na + Cl &-> NaCl}&&\text{(fast step)}\\
\end{align}

Using Hess' law, we can combine these to make sure it equals the original equation.
$$\require{cancel} 
\begin{align}
\ce{  && Na + Cl2 &-> NaCl + \cancel{Cl}}\\
\ce{+ && Na + \cancel{Cl} &-> NaCl} \\\hline
\ce{  && 2Na + Cl2 &-> 2NaCl} \\
\end{align}$$

The coefficients of the slowest elementary step in reaction mechanism determine the exponents of the rate law. Hence:
$$\text{Rate}=k[\ce{Na}]^{1}[\ce{Cl2}]^{1}$$

Or just
$$\text{Rate}=k[\ce{Na}][\ce{Cl2}].$$

Comment: What about that part where sodium is a solid?